# При огромном количестве HTTP-запросов DNS не резолвит домены

Tags: многопоточность, dns, bind

Мне нужно проверить 200 миллионов доменов на доступность и приндлежность к той или иной CMS.

Я использую PHP 7.1 и делаю проверку большим количеством процессов.

### Железо и настройки

1. Сервер: Multicore CPU, 64GB RAM, SSD disks, 500 Mbits dedicated bandwidth (OVH server).
2. В файле resolv.conf Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4
3. ulimit -n установлен в значение 655350
4. Использую nload для анализа загрузки канала

### Тестирование

Я проверял первый 1 миллион доменов из БД изпользуя разное количество параллельно запущенных процессов. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что увеличивая количество процессов, количество доменов, которые не отвечают в течение 30 секунд, сильно увеличилось. Вот результаты.

**1. 1000 процессов**

*Тест: 1,000,000 доменов, 1000 параллельных процессов, средняя загрузка канала 85 Mbits, общее время проверки 1 час.
Результат: **65% доменов успешно зарезолвлены**, 35% не были зарезолвлены из-за таймаута.*

**2. 300 процессов**

*Тест: 1,000,000 доменов, 300 параллельных процессов, средняя загрузка канала 70 Mbits, общее время проверки 2 часа.
Результат: **85% доменов успешно зарезолвлены**, 15% не были зарезолвлены из-за таймаута.*

### Выводы

Как мы можем видеть, увеличивая количество процессов в 3 раза, мы не получаем увеличение загрузки канала в 3 раза. 
Сильно увеличивается количество доменов, которые не были доступны/незарезолвлены. При этом скорость проверки была увеличена в 2 раза.

### Вопрос

Где узкое место такой проверки? Как я могу использовать всю пропускную способность канала в 500 Mbit? Должен ли я использовать свой собственный DNS сервер и если так, то как его правильно сконфигурировать?

Буду рад любым идеям и советам!

Comment: Использование количества потоков превышающего количество ядер процессора не целесообразно и ведет к гигантским накладным расходам на переключение контекста. теоретически часть таймаутов может быть связана даже с тем, что процессам вовремя не доставался процессор. Кроме того стандартная библиотека резолва ОС так же не рассчитана на такое. Необходимо использовать отдельную асинхронную библиотеку резолва. И очень желательно после резолва остальные действия так же выполнять небольшим количеством потоков в асинхронном режиме.

Comment: После этого уже смотреть на каком именно этапе происходит какое количество таймаутов. При разрешении имен или при последующем соединении с хостом. Так же стоит обратить внимание на всю промежуточную инфраструктуру при соединении с интернетом, включая часть у провайдера. Очень многие маршрутизаторы домашнего класса не справятся с таким количеством соединений. Так же многие провайдеры, заявляющие 500 МБит при этом режут количество одновременных подключений. А даже если и не режут, но используют NAT у них может переполняться NAT таблица

Comment: Кроме этого никаких данных по ограничениям на DNS серверах 8.8.8.8 я не видел, но они вполне могут быть. Но если будете использовать собственный DNS сервер, то это может привести к гораздо большей нагрузке на таблицу NAT. Так что в идеале вам надо убедится что никакого NAT в принципе нет нигде на маршруте.

Comment: И так же заметьте, что замер загрузки канала в мегабитах имеет смысл только при скачивании большого объема информации. А при вашей нагрузке небольшими запросами на огромное количество хостов мегабиты уже практически не имеют такой ценности. Узкое место вообще может оказаться например в обработке прерываний вашей сетевой картой. На таких скоростях крайне рекомендуются серверные сетевые карты и возможно тюнинг обработки прерываний в ОС (в плоть до фиксации ядра обрабатывающего прерывания и снятия с него другой нагрузки)